# difference between select from dual and execute immediate oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
select SUM(ABCD.COUNTRY_CODE) from AB_SRP_DETAILS_ALL ABCD 
where rownum <= 1
```

is INVALID when column COUNTRY_CODE is a varchar2 column but the same query when fired using execute immediate is valid

Comment: "invalid" is not an Oracle error. The statement looks OK other than it is relying on implicit conversion of the string values to numbers, so if you have values that can't be converted it will error, however you run it. And NLS settings might affect whether it works too. You shouldn't be storing numbers as strings though. If youre country codes are actually string like GB or GBR then summing wouldn't make sense. Without seeing your PL/SQL code, I'm guessing you aren't supplying an `into` clause, so the statement isn't actually run. Impossible to tell from what you have shown though.

Comment: Try removing the condition [where rownum <= 1] and execute immediate - see if it fails.

Comment: even if you use `execute immediate`, the query should raise ORA-01722.

Comment: Incidentally, the `rownum` filter is pointless as the query will always return exactly one row (unless it errors...), but it shouldn't itself cause an error. Even if the country codes are supposed to be numeric, summing them doesn't seem to make much sense. Maybe you meant `count(abcd.country_code)` which would tell you how many non-null values there are, or perhaps more likely `count(distinct abcd.country_code)` to see how many different countries there are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a simpler (but illogical) query:

```
select sum(dummy) from dual;

Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number

begin
  execute immediate 'select sum(dummy) from dual';
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

So why does the first statement throw an error, but the second one does not?

As [noted in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8__GUID-03324D0E-5267-42B9-98BE-8325F9213352):

> If *dynamic_sql_statement* is a `SELECT` statement, and you omit both *into_clause* and *bulk_collect_into_clause*, then *execute_immediate_statement* never executes.

The `execute immediate` in my PL/SQL block does not have an `into` clause, so the query is not executed, and as it isn't executed it doesn't generate the exception. The query statement is still *parsed*, so if the syntax was invalid an error would be seen; but the ORA-01722 is a run-time error thrown by query execution not during parsing.

A slightly more realistic PL/SQL version does throw the same error:

```
declare
  result number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select sum(dummy) from dual' into result;
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-06512: at line 4
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```